I am trying to download an Image using URL in react native for android and IOS
For android its working but for ios im getting undefined
**
LOG  Image downloaded at: undefined/image_1716340223058.png
**
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const App = () => {
  const image =
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/785080/pexels-photo-785080.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800';

  const downloadImageRemote = () => {
    let date = new Date();
    let image_URL = image;
    let ext = '.png';
    let PictureDir = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath;
    let imageName =
      'image_' + Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) + ext;
    let imagePath = `${PictureDir}/${imageName}`;

    RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: image_URL,
      toFile: imagePath,
      background: true,
      discretionary: true,
    })
      .promise.then(res => {
        console.log('Image downloaded at:', imagePath);
        Alert.alert('Image Downloaded Successfully.');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Download failed:', error);
        Alert.alert('Download failed. Please try again later.');
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={image} placeholder="Enter text" />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => downloadImageRemote()}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    width: '80%',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default App;


Can anyone help?
I trid changing the path but not woking
I tride loggin this  Image downloaded at: /Users/monishreddy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DF04A1EA-BC7E-49F9-BB47-24EC599C9CD5/data/Containers/Data/Application/65A998A4-E032-4F3D-9A1A-64137D1786F2/Library/image_1716340650288.png

iOS is sandboxed, and it does not have DownloadDirectoryPath like android.
Constants

The following constants are available on the RNFS export:

MainBundlePath (String) The absolute path to the main bundle directory (not available on Android)
CachesDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the caches directory
ExternalCachesDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the external caches directory (android only)
DocumentDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the document directory
DownloadDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the download directory (on android and Windows only)
TemporaryDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the temporary directory (falls back to Caching-Directory on Android)
LibraryDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the NSLibraryDirectory (iOS only)
ExternalDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the external files, shared directory (android only)
ExternalStorageDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the external storage, shared directory (android only)
PicturesDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the pictures directory (Windows only)
RoamingDirectoryPath (String) The absolute path to the roaming directory (Windows only)

As you can see from above, RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath is not available on iOS. Replace it with some folder like DocumentDirectoryPath instead.
See Constants for details.

Try to change to RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath, because DownloadDirectoryPath is not available on iOS.
let PictureDir = Platform.OS === 'ios'? RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath : RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath;


Can you provide bit more information regarding the decision making and other custom info. Please check other answers.
